# Add to every line starting with "exp_send" before and after match

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to add to every line starting with "exp_send" something at the beginning and at the end.

Example:

```
    } "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? " {
        exp_send -i $sid -- "yes\r"
    } "password" {
        exp_send -i $sid -- "$password\r"
        exp_send -i $sid -- "\r\r\r"
```

will be:

```
    } "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? " {
      aaa exp_send -i $sid -- "yes\r" bbb
    } "password" {
       aaa exp_send -i $sid -- "$password\r" bbb
       aaa exp_send -i $sid -- "\r\r\r" bbb
```

What is the regexp to use?

Note:

I found this to be helpful :

```
search : ^.(exp_send).$
replace : aaa\1bbb
```

But it removes the tabs ... what is else needed ?

Comment: why not just replace exp_send with the thing you want it to do?  It's not hard to do that in expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

Find what: `^(\s*)(exp_send.*)$`
Replace with: `$1aaa $2 bbb`

If you want to add text on newline with same tabulation:

Find what: `^(\s*)(exp_send.*)$`
Replace with: `$1$2\n$1bbb`

Comment: I will ! , BTW , if i want to add "bbb" in new line but tabed the same, How would i do it ?